# Ranked Teams question?

Tags: league-of-legends

The season is over and the rewards have been released. I made it to silver with a ranked team in 3's, managing to barely get silver rewards for it. So my question is what would happen if I leave that team now during the pre-season? Possible outcomes would I guess be; First nothing changes, Second I simply lose the silver symbol on my profile for 3's, Third I could also see like lolnexus forgetting my highest rank was silver in the "Last season highest" thing. I'm not sure though, I'd like to believe you wouldn't lose silver rewards considering they were already given out, like the icon, etc.

Just Curious.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You won't lose your rewards.

With regards to the silver badge on your profile that indicates success this season, I am not 100 percent sure if you will lose it or not (I don't think you will), but I do know that it doesn't matter much since S4 will start soon. You will lose that symbol when S4 starts and have to earn it as part of an S4 Team. So it would only be missing a few weeks at most even if it did disappear temporarily

Its not feasible to answer what effects leaving would have on 3rd party sites, since there are a lot of them and they aren't necessarily well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Season 3 is complete, season 4 just hasn't started yet.

Any rewards you obtained from the season will stay, such as the silver border on your profile at the top.

The silver icon on the profile for 3v3s will disappear. If you are not on a ranked team that has played any games of that type, then it has no stats for it to show, and it will remove the icon from your profile.

Your accomplishments in the season will remain on sites like lolnexus for season 3 on that team, even if you decide to leave it now.